Evict node from SQL Server 2016 AlwaysOn
I have 3 nodes cluster on Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2016 installed with AlwaysOn.
I would like to remove 1 nodes from the cluster.
What is the correct way to perform it ?
Is there a risk of downtime?
Also is uninstalling SQL Server necessary?
Steps:
1- Remove unwanted nodes from Always on Replicas.
2- Evict these nodes from Windows Failover Cluster.
My questions are:
1 -  How can I remove the power off server from the cluster? Is it possible to delete from GUI or with powershell? I will use Remove-ClusterNode -Name sql03 ? Do I have to use Clear-ClusterNode -Name sql03 command as well?
2 -  What are the considerations about the quorum voting?
currently quorom vote as follows , if I evict sql03 from cluster then will there be any downtime?
current host server : sql01
file share witness :\file01\sqlcls
sql01  assigned vote : 1   current vote: 1
sql02  assigned vote : 1   current vote: 0
sql03  assigned vote : 1   current vote: 0


Cluster        : sqlcls
QuorumResource : File Share Witness
QuorumType     : Majority

Get-Cluster | Ft Name, DynamicQuorum, WitnessDynamicWeight -Autosize

Name          DynamicQuorum WitnessDynamicWeight
----          ------------- --------------------
sqlcls             1                    0


Get-ClusterNode | Ft NodeName, DynamicWeight , NodeWeight -Autosize

NodeName       DynamicWeight NodeWeight
--------       ------------- ----------
sql03             0            1
sql01             1            1
sql02             0            1

